# Only the first occurrence

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

I have this string `MIL_A_OP=LI_AND=SSB12=JL45==DO=90==IT=KR002112`
and I need to **split it into 2** , based on the first "="

so I need it to get:

first string: `MIL_A_OP`

second string: `LI_AND=SSB12=JL45==DO=90==IT`

this below code is what I have, but it gives me MIL_A_OP and LI_AND, I miss the rest

```
try
{
    StreamReader file1 = new StreamReader(args[0]);
    string line1;
    while ((line1 = file1.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line1 != null && line1.Trim().Length > 0)//if line is not empty
        {
            int position_1 = line1.IndexOf('=');
            string s_position_1 = line1.Substring(position_1, 1);
            char[] c_position_1 = s_position_1.ToCharArray(0,1);
            string[] line_split1 = line1.Split(c_position_1[0]);
            Foo.f1.Add(line_split1[0], line_split1[1]);
        }
    }
    file1.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File " + args[0] + " could not be read");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Your second `Split` just needs to be `Substring`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the overload of the Split() method that allows you to specify a maximum number of elements to return. Try this:

```
string[] line_split1 = line1.Split( new char[]{'='}, 2 );
```

[Documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx).

*Updated with Matthew's feedback.*

Comment: `line1.Split(new char[]{'='}, 2);` would probably be more succinct

Comment: I like this. but why I get the best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments. Argument 2: can not convert from int to char

Comment: @JohnRyann the example has a problem (`Split` requires an array but the example uses a scalar value).  See my comment.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following

```
string all = "MIL_A_OP=LI_AND=SSB12=JL45==DO=90==IT=KR002112";
int index = all.IndexOf('=');
if (index < 0) {
  throw new Exception("Bad data");
}
var first = all.Substring(0, index);
var second = all.Substring(index + 1, all.Length - (index + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you line always contains the = char, then the following should work

```
string[] line_split1 = line.Split( new char[] {'='} , 2);

if (line_split1.Length != 2)
    throw new Exception ("Invalid format");
```